# Service Fabric "Waiting for upgrade..." using VSTS

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I've configured upgrades on my VSTS release of a Service Fabric app containing 5 services to a single node test environment on Azure. Unfortunately when it gets to the release part it just hangs saying "Waiting for upgrade..." over and over again. I left it for 15 hours and it still says the same thing. The initial deployment went ahead without issue.

I've looked at various posts about turning off health check times, but this has not been successful. I've also tried setting the mode to UnmonitoredAuto, but no success.

I've RDPd onto the environment and checked the processor/memory usage in task manager, and everything is pretty much 0%, and very low memory usage.

Is there anything else I can do to stop the upgrade hanging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've managed to fix this. This was happening because there is a PreUpgradeSafetyCheck that happens before rolling out an upgrade. This is not relevant for a single node cluster as downtime is inevitable for single node clusters.

The status of an upgrade can be found using: Get-ServiceFabricApplicationUpgrade. Which shows the status above.

To fix this there is a flag: UpgradeReplicaSetCheckTimeoutSec in the release task. Setting the value to 0 sorts things out.